# Problema con Bucles for, while y do while en C

Tags: c

/*se solicita 10 números enteros positivos, calcular y mostrar los siguientes valores, la suma de todo los números leídos, la media de los números ,
el mayor numero introducido y el menor numero introducido */

Estoy confundido en como puedo ingresar la media y determinar cal es mayor y cual es menor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deberias almacenar los numeros en un vector de 10 posiciones un numero por cada posicion e indexarlo con la "i" y eso acumularlo en suma
para sacar el mayor tenes que hacerlo dentro de un bucle for y al menor tambien por separado y la media estaria  bien. se entendio?

Answer (score 0):

Si eres capaz de calcular la suma ya tienes la media, ya que:

```
    media = suma / 10
```

Para calcular el mayor y el menor puedes crear dos variables y a cada iteración por el bucle comprueba si el número actual es mayor que el mayor y menor que el menor para actualizar el valor. Por ejemplo:

```
     float numero, mayor, menor, suma;
     int i;

     printf("Dame un número: ");
     scanf("%d\n", &numero);
     mayor = menor = suma = numero;

     for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
     {
         printf("Dame un número: ");
         scanf("%d\n", &numero);

         suma += numero;

         if (numero > mayor)
             mayor = numero;
         else if (numero < menor)
             menor = numero;
     }

     media = suma / 10;
```

No lo he probado, pero te puedes hacer una idea leyendo este código de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, el programa lo acomode y pues no me genera el resultado esperado pero ya tengo una idea de donde partir muchas gracias amigo, acepto de igual manera cualquier otra sugerencia!